# How to reset sounds in Yosemite 10.10.3

Tags: macos, audio, sound-volume

In an earlier OSX release, the combination `alt-cmd-P-R` reenabled sounds after a restart, but not in Yosemite.

In some version of OSX, the command `sudo killall coreaudio` works but not in Yosemite 10.10.3 on a mid-2013 MacBook Air.
This problem occurred also in Yosemite 10.10.1 when upgrading to the new release.
I managed to get sounds back by the above procedures.

I see no audio sources in sound settings after this problem appeared, even after those two attempts to solve this problem.

[image]

How can you reset sounds in OSX Yosemite 10.10.3?

I can get free AppleCare support if it is the only solution, since I have 5 year insurance.
However, I do not want to do it if there is no other solution.

## Events 23.5.2015

Apple brought new updates in App Store which solved the problem temporarily (3 hours):

[image]

I used my Macbook air 3 hours, went to pause and opened the Macbook again - the same problem came back.
I do not really understand the reason of OSX bug.

The command `cd /System/Library/Extensions/AudioAUUC.kext ; ls -alt` gives

```
total 136
drwxr-xr-x  245 root  wheel   8330 May  3 12:06 ..
drwxr-xr-x    6 root  wheel    204 Apr 23 19:19 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 root  wheel    102 Apr 23 19:19 _CodeSignature
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel  57392 Mar 23 20:44 AudioAUUC
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    473 Mar 23 20:44 version.plist
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel   2251 Mar 23 20:44 Info.plist
```

which are rather new.

The command `kextstat -b com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC` gives

```
Index Refs Address Size Wired Name (Version) <Linked Against>
```

which means that the audio thing is not loaded as discussed with @danielAzuelos.

Daniel's command `/usr/bin/sudo kextutil -t -v 6 -b com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC` gives

```
Kext user-space log filter changed from 0xff2 to 0xfff.
Kext kernel-space log filter changed from 0xff2 to 0xfff.
Kext library architecture set to x86_64.
Can't stat /AppleInternal - No such file or directory.
Defaulting to kernel file '/System/Library/Kernels/kernel'
Kext library recording diagnostics for: validation authentication dependencies warnings.
/System/Library/Extensions/AudioAUUC.kext appears to be loadable (not including linkage for on-disk libraries).
Reading loaded kext info from kernel.
(kernel) User-space log flags changed from 0x0 to 0xfff.
(kernel) Received 'Get Loaded Kext Info' request from user space.
(kernel) Returning loaded kext info.
Loaded kext info:
{
}

Loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioAUUC.kext.
Reading load info for 13 kexts.
Reading loaded kext info from kernel.
(kernel) User-space log flags changed from 0x0 to 0xfff.
(kernel) Received 'Get Loaded Kext Info' request from user space.
(kernel) Returning loaded kext info.
Loaded kext info:
{
"com.apple.kpi.bsd" = {
    "OSBundleWiredSize" = 35920
    "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.kpi.bsd"
    "OSBundleUUID" = <a0e026bd b5be44f7 8403a871 8d3dbaca>
    "OSBundleLoadAddress" = -551892557824
    "OSBundleLoadTag" = 1
    "OSBundleStarted" = true
    "OSBundleCompatibleVersion" = "8.0.0b1"
    "OSKernelResource" = true
    "CFBundleVersion" = "14.3.0"
    "OSBundlePath" = 
        "/System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/BSDKernel.kext"
    "OSBundleRetainCount" = 76
    "OSBundlePrelinked" = true
    "OSBundleIsInterface" = true
    "OSBundleLoadSize" = 35920
}
"com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily" = {
    "OSBundleWiredSize" = 192512
    "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily"
    "OSBundleStarted" = true
    "OSBundleCPUType" = 16777223
    "OSBundleCompatibleVersion" = "1.0.0b1"
    "OSBundleUUID" = <52e715fc 521d3869 b2ea5228 fa4bea34>
    "OSKernelResource" = false
    "CFBundleVersion" = "2.9"
    "OSBundleLoadTag" = 12
    "OSBundleLoadAddress" = -551891615744
    "OSBundleDependencies" = (
        4
        5
        3
        7
        6
    )
    "OSBundlePath" = "/System/Library/Extensions/IOPCIFamily.kext"
    "OSBundleRetainCount" = 27
    "OSBundleCPUSubtype" = 3
    "OSBundlePrelinked" = true
    "OSBundleIsInterface" = false
    "OSBundleLoadSize" = 192512
}
"com.apple.kpi.unsupported" = {
    "OSBundleWiredSize" = 18688
    "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.kpi.unsupported"
    "OSBundleUUID" = <6b59e72c 5a8a4f6f 9f1fac1a c266fc01>
    "OSBundleLoadAddress" = -551892578304
    "OSBundleLoadTag" = 7
    "OSBundleStarted" = true
    "OSBundleCompatibleVersion" = "8.0.0b1"
    "OSKernelResource" = true
    "CFBundleVersion" = "14.3.0"
    "OSBundlePath" = 
        "/System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/Unsupported.kext"
    "OSBundleRetainCount" = 59
    "OSBundlePrelinked" = true
    "OSBundleIsInterface" = true
    "OSBundleLoadSize" = 18688
}
"com.apple.kec.Libm" = {
    "OSBundleWiredSize" = 36864
    "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.kec.Libm"
    "OSBundleStarted" = true
    "OSBundleCPUType" = 16777223
    "OSBundleCompatibleVersion" = "1.0.0d0"
    "OSBundleUUID" = <a085de81 421e3818 b5aa3176 f8a9ee41>
    "OSKernelResource" = false
    "CFBundleVersion" = "1"
    "OSBundleLoadTag" = 10
    "OSBundleLoadAddress" = -551887593472
    "OSBundleDependencies" = (
        4
    )
    "OSBundlePath" = "/System/Library/Extensions/Libm.kext"
    "OSBundleRetainCount" = 1
    "OSBundleCPUSubtype" = 3
    "OSBundlePrelinked" = true
    "OSBundleIsInterface" = false
    "OSBundleLoadSize" = 36864
}
"com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily" = {
    "OSBundleWiredSize" = 196608
    "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily"
    "OSBundleStarted" = true
    "OSBundleCPUType" = 16777223
    "OSBundleCompatibleVersion" = "1.0"
    "OSBundleUUID" = <76e5591a b4953994 82c9d4af e7248acd>
    "OSKernelResource" = false
    "CFBundleVersion" = "203.3"
    "OSBundleLoadTag" = 104
    "OSBundleLoadAddress" = -551870152704
    "OSBundleDependencies" = (
        1
        4
        3
        103
        5
    )
    "OSBundlePath" = "/System/Library/Extensions/IOAudioFamily.kext"
    "OSBundleRetainCount" = 1
    "OSBundleCPUSubtype" = 3
    "OSBundlePrelinked" = true
    "OSBundleIsInterface" = false
    "OSBundleLoadSize" = 196608
}
"com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily" = {
    "OSBundleWiredSize" = 36864
    "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily"
    "OSBundleStarted" = true
    "OSBundleCPUType" = 16777223
    "OSBundleCompatibleVersion" = "1.0.0d1"
    "OSBundleUUID" = <70e2b65e a91a3522 a1a079fd 63eabb4c>
    "OSKernelResource" = false
    "CFBundleVersion" = "1.4"
    "OSBundleLoadTag" = 11
    "OSBundleLoadAddress" = -551882403840
    "OSBundleDependencies" = (
        6
        4
        3
        7
    )
    "OSBundlePath" = "/System/Library/Extensions/IOACPIFamily.kext"
    "OSBundleRetainCount" = 21
    "OSBundleCPUSubtype" = 3
    "OSBundlePrelinked" = true
    "OSBundleIsInterface" = false
    "OSBundleLoadSize" = 36864
}
"com.apple.kpi.iokit" = {
    "OSBundleWiredSize" = 132352
    "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.kpi.iokit"
    "OSBundleUUID" = <2ce5bfc8 851e42a0 89c2c72c 5fc0ed37>
    "OSBundleLoadAddress" = -551892799488
    "OSBundleLoadTag" = 3
    "OSBundleStarted" = true
    "OSBundleCompatibleVersion" = "7.0"
    "OSKernelResource" = true
    "CFBundleVersion" = "14.3.0"
    "OSBundlePath" = 
        "/System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/IOKit.kext"
    "OSBundleRetainCount" = 99
    "OSBundlePrelinked" = true
    "OSBundleIsInterface" = true
    "OSBundleLoadSize" = 132352
}
"com.apple.kpi.mach" = {
    "OSBundleWiredSize" = 11600
    "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.kpi.mach"
    "OSBundleUUID" = <25a0bcf1 1ba54d24 8bc20d3e ce0e2290>
    "OSBundleLoadAddress" = -551892811776
    "OSBundleLoadTag" = 5
    "OSBundleStarted" = true
    "OSBundleCompatibleVersion" = "8.0.0d0"
    "OSKernelResource" = true
    "CFBundleVersion" = "14.3.0"
    "OSBundlePath" = "/System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/Mach.kext"
    "OSBundleRetainCount" = 90
    "OSBundlePrelinked" = true
    "OSBundleIsInterface" = true
    "OSBundleLoadSize" = 11600
}
"com.apple.vecLib.kext" = {
    "OSBundleWiredSize" = 491520
    "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.vecLib.kext"
    "OSBundleStarted" = true
    "OSBundleCPUType" = 16777223
    "OSBundleCompatibleVersion" = "1.0.0d0"
    "OSBundleUUID" = <f806e076 fbc83e43 925ec85b dba433db>
    "OSKernelResource" = false
    "CFBundleVersion" = "1.2.0"
    "OSBundleLoadTag" = 103
    "OSBundleLoadAddress" = -551870644224
    "OSBundleDependencies" = (
        10
        4
        3
        6
        5
    )
    "OSBundlePath" = "/System/Library/Extensions/vecLib.kext"
    "OSBundleRetainCount" = 1
    "OSBundleCPUSubtype" = 3
    "OSBundlePrelinked" = true
    "OSBundleIsInterface" = false
    "OSBundleLoadSize" = 491520
}
"com.apple.kpi.private" = {
    "OSBundleWiredSize" = 34192
    "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.kpi.private"
    "OSBundleUUID" = <defc5a97 5f574cad b525506a eb855330>
    "OSBundleLoadAddress" = -551892615168
    "OSBundleLoadTag" = 6
    "OSBundleStarted" = true
    "OSBundleCompatibleVersion" = "8.0.0b1"
    "OSKernelResource" = true
    "CFBundleVersion" = "14.3.0"
    "OSBundlePath" = 
        "/System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/Private.kext"
    "OSBundleRetainCount" = 43
    "OSBundlePrelinked" = true
    "OSBundleIsInterface" = true
    "OSBundleLoadSize" = 34192
}
"com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily" = {
    "OSBundleWiredSize" = 241664
    "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily"
    "OSBundleStarted" = true
    "OSBundleCPUType" = 16777223
    "OSBundleCompatibleVersion" = "1.0.0b1"
    "OSBundleUUID" = <82ead591 67e339cb a232a809 5ca30e92>
    "OSKernelResource" = false
    "CFBundleVersion" = "2.4.1"
    "OSBundleLoadTag" = 77
    "OSBundleLoadAddress" = -551881777152
    "OSBundleDependencies" = (
        12
        4
        3
        7
        5
        1
    )
    "OSBundlePath" = "/System/Library/Extensions/IOGraphicsFamily.kext"
    "OSBundleRetainCount" = 11
    "OSBundleCPUSubtype" = 3
    "OSBundlePrelinked" = true
    "OSBundleIsInterface" = false
    "OSBundleLoadSize" = 241664
}
"com.apple.kpi.libkern" = {
    "OSBundleWiredSize" = 48976
    "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.kpi.libkern"
    "OSBundleUUID" = <7b658b96 3b784a9c 9a975c63 a8f653fe>
    "OSBundleLoadAddress" = -551892664320
    "OSBundleLoadTag" = 4
    "OSBundleStarted" = true
    "OSBundleCompatibleVersion" = "8.0.0d0"
    "OSKernelResource" = true
    "CFBundleVersion" = "14.3.0"
    "OSBundlePath" = 
        "/System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/Libkern.kext"
    "OSBundleRetainCount" = 104
    "OSBundlePrelinked" = true
    "OSBundleIsInterface" = true
    "OSBundleLoadSize" = 48976
}
}

/System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/BSDKernel.kext (version 14.3, UUID A0E026BD-B5BE-44F7-8403-A8718D3DBACA) is loaded.
/System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/BSDKernel.kext (version 14.3): is started.
setting load address of /System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/BSDKernel.kext to 0xffffff7f80a3e000
/System/Library/Extensions/IOACPIFamily.kext (version 1.4, UUID 70E2B65E-A91A-3522-A1A0-79FD63EABB4C) is loaded.
/System/Library/Extensions/IOACPIFamily.kext (version 1.4): is started.
setting load address of /System/Library/Extensions/IOACPIFamily.kext to 0xffffff7f813ed000
/System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/Libkern.kext (version 14.3, UUID 7B658B96-3B78-4A9C-9A97-5C63A8F653FE) is loaded.
/System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/Libkern.kext (version 14.3): is started.
setting load address of /System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/Libkern.kext to 0xffffff7f80a24000
/System/Library/Extensions/IOPCIFamily.kext (version 2.9, UUID 52E715FC-521D-3869-B2EA-5228FA4BEA34) is loaded.
/System/Library/Extensions/IOPCIFamily.kext (version 2.9): is started.
setting load address of /System/Library/Extensions/IOPCIFamily.kext to 0xffffff7f80b24000
/System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/IOKit.kext (version 14.3, UUID 2CE5BFC8-851E-42A0-89C2-C72C5FC0ED37) is loaded.
/System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/IOKit.kext (version 14.3): is started.
setting load address of /System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/IOKit.kext to 0xffffff7f80a03000
/System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/Mach.kext (version 14.3, UUID 25A0BCF1-1BA5-4D24-8BC2-0D3ECE0E2290) is loaded.
/System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/Mach.kext (version 14.3): is started.
setting load address of /System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/Mach.kext to 0xffffff7f80a00000
/System/Library/Extensions/IOAudioFamily.kext (version 203.3, UUID 76E5591A-B495-3994-82C9-D4AFE7248ACD) is loaded.
/System/Library/Extensions/IOAudioFamily.kext (version 203.3): is started.
setting load address of /System/Library/Extensions/IOAudioFamily.kext to 0xffffff7f81f9c000
/System/Library/Extensions/IOGraphicsFamily.kext (version 2.4.1, UUID 82EAD591-67E3-39CB-A232-A8095CA30E92) is loaded.
/System/Library/Extensions/IOGraphicsFamily.kext (version 2.4.1): is started.
setting load address of /System/Library/Extensions/IOGraphicsFamily.kext to 0xffffff7f81486000
/System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/Unsupported.kext (version 14.3, UUID 6B59E72C-5A8A-4F6F-9F1F-AC1AC266FC01) is loaded.
/System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/Unsupported.kext (version 14.3): is started.
setting load address of /System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/Unsupported.kext to 0xffffff7f80a39000
/System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/Private.kext (version 14.3, UUID DEFC5A97-5F57-4CAD-B525-506AEB855330) is loaded.
/System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/Private.kext (version 14.3): is started.
setting load address of /System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/Private.kext to 0xffffff7f80a30000
/System/Library/Extensions/vecLib.kext (version 1.2, UUID F806E076-FBC8-3E43-925E-C85BDBA433DB) is loaded.
/System/Library/Extensions/vecLib.kext (version 1.2): is started.
setting load address of /System/Library/Extensions/vecLib.kext to 0xffffff7f81f24000
/System/Library/Extensions/Libm.kext (version 1.0, UUID A085DE81-421E-3818-B5AA-3176F8A9EE41) is loaded.
/System/Library/Extensions/Libm.kext (version 1.0): is started.
setting load address of /System/Library/Extensions/Libm.kext to 0xffffff7f80efa000
Omitting loaded kext /System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/BSDKernel.kext from mkext for kernel load.
Omitting loaded kext /System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/Unsupported.kext from mkext for kernel load.
Omitting loaded kext /System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/IOKit.kext from mkext for kernel load.
Omitting loaded kext /System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/Libkern.kext from mkext for kernel load.
Omitting loaded kext /System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/Private.kext from mkext for kernel load.
Omitting loaded kext /System/Library/Extensions/IOACPIFamily.kext from mkext for kernel load.
Omitting loaded kext /System/Library/Extensions/System.kext/PlugIns/Mach.kext from mkext for kernel load.
Omitting loaded kext /System/Library/Extensions/IOPCIFamily.kext from mkext for kernel load.
Omitting loaded kext /System/Library/Extensions/Libm.kext from mkext for kernel load.
Omitting loaded kext /System/Library/Extensions/vecLib.kext from mkext for kernel load.
Omitting loaded kext /System/Library/Extensions/IOAudioFamily.kext from mkext for kernel load.
Omitting loaded kext /System/Library/Extensions/IOGraphicsFamily.kext from mkext for kernel load.
Adding /System/Library/Extensions/AudioAUUC.kext to mkext.
/System/Library/Extensions/AudioAUUC.kext added 57392-byte noncompressed executable to mkext.
Created mkext for architecture x86_64 containing 1 kexts.
Loading /System/Library/Extensions/AudioAUUC.kext.
(kernel) User-space log flags changed from 0x0 to 0xfff.
(kernel) Received kext load request from user space.
(kernel) Received request from user space to load kext com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC.
(kernel) Recorded kext com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC as a candidate for inclusion in prelinked kernel.
(kernel) Loading kext com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.kpi.bsd is already loaded.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily is already loaded.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily sending 0 personality to the IOCatalogue and starting matching.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.kpi.libkern is already loaded.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily is already loaded.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily sending 3 personalities to the IOCatalogue and starting matching.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.kpi.iokit is already loaded.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.kpi.mach is already loaded.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily is already loaded.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily is already loaded.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.kpi.unsupported is already loaded.
(kernel) Allocated link buffer for kext com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC at 0xffffff7f9a203000 (28672 bytes).
(kernel) Kext com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC executable loaded; 7 pages at 0xffffff7f82a03000 (load tag 142).
(kernel) Kext com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC calling module start function.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC registered class AudioAUUCDriver.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC has IOService subclass AudioAUUCDriver; enabling autounload.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC registered class AudioAUUC.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC is now started.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC sending 1 personality to the IOCatalogue and starting matching.
(kernel) Kext com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC loaded.
Successfully loaded /System/Library/Extensions/AudioAUUC.kext.
/System/Library/Extensions/AudioAUUC.kext successfully loaded (or already loaded).
```

and I see that the module is not loaded as the output `Index Refs Address            Size       Wired      Name (Version) <Linked Against>` of the command `kextstat -b com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC`.

**How can you load this audio thing now?**

Comment: Do you mean so that the startup chime sounds at every boot?

Comment: @Rajiv No. All sounds are off in my Macbook. I cannot hear anything.

Comment: Is it possible that you're running a program that mutes all other output except itself, but the program isn't playing anything? For example, during a FaceTime call, any music playing in iTunes is turned so low that it's almost inaudible.

Comment: @Rajiv No, it is not possible. I have had this problem many times before in several OSX and different versions of laptops: Macbook, Macbook Pro and Macbook Air. The problem is in Apple's software-hardware where they have not managed to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are talking here of very risky component of the kernel coming from the disk, the first hypothesis to kill is a corrupted file system.

1. Check your boot partition with Disk Utility.

   If errors appear, repair it, and reboot.
2. Check for extension problem:

   Reboot your Mac without extensions: [OS X Yosemite: Start up in safe mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18760)

   If you don't hear the boot chime sound, just press the <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd> 3 seconds after the power on button. Keep it depressed until you see the dark grey progression bar showing the extensions, cache and kernel reorganization in progress.

   Check if the sound is OK.

   If yes, start the hunt for the bad extension.

   If not, you have an hardware problem. Bring your Mac to Apple.
3. Check for extension, cache or kernel corruption:

   Verify if the audio kernel extensions are actually loaded:

   ```
   kextstat | egrep 'Index|Audio'
   ```

   You should get an output very similar (but the hex address field) to this:

   ```
   $ kextstat | egrep 'Index|Audio'
   Index Refs Address            Size       Wired      Name (Version) <Linked Against>
          95    4 0xffffff7f81603000 0x30000    0x30000    com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily (203.3) <94 5 4 3 1>
         196    0 0xffffff7f82c24000 0x5000     0x5000     com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC (1.70) <95 76 12 11 7 5 4 3 1>
   $
   ```

   If you don't have these 2 extensions loaded, you will take advantage of this default to load them in a mode where you will see what is going wrong (i.e. what is usually hidden behind the *nice spinning beach balloon®*).

   To manually reload a missing extension and to take advantage of this manual operation to better understand the origin of the bad, here is how to proceed:

   ```
   /usr/bin/sudo kextutil -t -v 6 -b com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC
   ```

   which loads the kernel extension `com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC`

   `-b` identify it with its bundle name,

   `-t` print diagnostics,

   `-v 6` will be as verbose as possible about every steps of this process.

   At the end of this verbose kernel extension loading, check that the kernel has loaded this extension:

   ```
   kextstat -b com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It could be hardware related: plug a headphone into the computer and make sure it really connects. Disconnect it and reboot. I had a MacMini with defect audio and this helped to get it up for a while. If no startup sound appears, try the same again but let the headphone plugged in. Experiment with this.

Note: When no startup chime appears, it probably means that the audio hardware couldn't get initialized and everything software related can't change a thing since the audio driver has no connection to the hardware.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! No change after plugging in and out headphone and rebooting multiple times.

Comment: Ok! Thank you for the feedback. BTW: I just remembered that we can set some audio properties with /Applications/Utilities/Audio MIDI Setup.app, for example you can choose what format an audio output has. Since there is no usable audio output this won't help but it is good to know that this app can do this (it has an "Audio Devices" panel and it can also test/configure the speakers).